# T-SQL Parameterized query with declared variable inside?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, ado.net

Here is my code I'm trying to execute:

```
const string Script = @"
DECLARE @AccountKey Int
SELECT @AccountKey = AccountKey FROM dbo.CREAccount WHERE AccountId = @AccountId 
INSERT dbo.CREException (CreatedOn, Message, Source, StackTrace, AccountKey, Category, Priority)
VALUES(GETUTCDATE(), @Message, @Source, @StackTrace, @AccountKey, @Category, @Priority)";

using (var command = new SqlCommand(Script, connection))
{
    var message = ex.Message;
    if (message.Length > 250) message = message.Substring(0, 250);

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Message", message));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Source", ex.Source ?? string.Empty));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StackTrace", ex.StackTrace ?? string.Empty));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccountId", accountId));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", category));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Priority", priority));

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As expected - it fails because @AccountKey is not specified in code - it is a parameter in T_SQL itself. How do I achieve what I want while using parameters? `accountId` parameter can be `null` - thats why I break down lookup and insert into 2 queries

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? I don't see any reason your SQL query would not work, I use this technique all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just rewrite your T-SQL to be:

```
INSERT INTO 
   dbo.CREException(CreatedOn, Message, Source, StackTrace, AccountKey, Category, Priority)
   SELECT       
      GETUTCDATE(), @Message, @Source, @StackTrace, 
      AccountKey, @Category, @Priority
   FROM 
      dbo.CREAccount 
   WHERE 
      AccountId = @AccountId
```

You still have all your parameters, and you're determining the value for `AccountKey` from the `dbo.CREAccount` table as in your example.

Maybe you need to think about providing a "default" value for `AccountKey` in case no value is found in the table...

Or if that doesn't work for some reason, then I'd probably just wrap up these two or three T-SQL statements into a stored procedure which you can call with the parameters and let that procedure handle all the extra steps you might need....

Comment: That was what I about to type :)

Comment: I don't want SP and yes, whole point of doing it like I do is because AccountKey can be NULL - so your SQL won't insert anything. I had it exactly like this but new requirement to allow NULLs in AccountKey

Comment: I hope there is answer on how to use parameters AND use paramters inside script :)

Comment: @katit: the only two solutions I see is to either (1) use a stored procedure (not clear why you're so against that - would solve your problem!), or (2) determine the value for `AccountKey` outside the T-SQL and pass that in as an additional parameter. I don't think there's any other way to solve this. Take your pick ....

Comment: Actually I made it to work. Used SELECT MIN(AccountKey) and that produced NULL when I needed

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to include @AccountKey as a sqlparmaeter, but change it's direction to Output?  That way you should still be able to select a value into it

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 

Add @AccountKey as a parameter.

cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccountKey", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Then remove the declaration in the query string. That'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the feedback to marc_s's answer, you could always make your sql look like this instead.

```
INSERT dbo.CREException (CreatedOn, Message, Source, StackTrace, AccountKey, Category, Priority)
VALUES(GETUTCDATE(), @Message, @Source, @StackTrace
,(SELECT AccountKey FROM dbo.CREAccount WHERE AccountId = @AccountId)
, @Category, @Priority)
```

If you want a default value for account key it would be easy enough to coalesce the result